# Android emulator set gps geolocation

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Is there any other way to set gps coordinates for the emulator? It does not work for the following methods:
1). `geo fix longitude, latitude [altitude]` If it does not work in terminal.

2)
[image: GPS Setting]

3) [image: DDMS Stting]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the emulator tool bar there should be ellipses you can click. Once you click them the Longitude and Latitude in that window are editable and will change the emulators perceived location.

[annotated image of where to find this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AKwj.png)

[image showing where to edit long and lat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uytlv.png)

Comment: where can I find the ellipses?

Comment: I added links to images so you can see where it is

Comment: Did you make sure to press the send button? It has always worked for me.

Comment: yes, it is also reported in the "currently reported location " block and if it had worked I would not be asking the question .

Comment: @FirefighterBlu3 yes

Comment: what additional steps did you take?

Comment: ok, discovered what made the difference. for most people doing android dev, they already have developer options enabled. on some phones, you need to have developer options enabled (tap 7+ times on Build Number) and enable mock locations

Comment: @FirefighterBlu3 you may need to check for app permissions too... when I tried try again this few days found I had not given the app some permission

Comment: @TechnoSniper i've granted both fine and coarse location permissions in the manifest, requested it at runtime, and returns permission_granted value each time i check it :} still can't get it to work on any of my other devices however

Comment: @FirefighterBlu3 log.d the files and check the values also check your  GPStracker

Answer (score 0):

An additional step may be needed on some phones which for Android developers, is most likely already done. Enable developer mode (tap 7+ times on Build Number) and turn on mock locations